# How to update env before every command (literally)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, tmux

I use many different VPNs for work and switch between them often using a script that sets up `$http_proxy` and `$https_proxy` for me. The issue is when I have a terminal open these variables won't update in that terminal's environment.

Is there a way to update environment of a process and child processes (or at least run some script but that's tricky*) before literally every command in terminal (including `ls`, `curl`, `sudo -e apt update`, etc.)? Preferably in a way that works for `bash`, `zsh`, `tmux` and all its children.

*) running a script before running any command is tricky because it can trigger itself over and over for every keyword of its own code (which I already did killing my machine like a master assassin - even I, the murderer, didn't know what killed the victim)

What I came up with so far is creating (and removing on exit) a `~/.proxy` file when running a VPN command to pass proxy config between environments but I still need to read it and update variables in each.

Comment: Sounds like you want to look at `preexec` for zsh, and [this](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec) implementation of it for bash.

Comment: I've never used them, but it sounds like you want [environment modules](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: @glennjackman I red through environment modules documentation and I don't think it's what I need, I'd still have to find a way to load and unload a module in every active environment.

Comment: @meuh I yet have to test exporting env variables from the function scope but it seems `preexec` is the thing I was looking for, thank you!